# I am getting an error "Invalid call. Nonexistent function 'set' in base 'Nil'."

Tags: godot, gdscript, onready

I am new to Godot. Trying to make a counter for some values of reactor core. Here is my code:

```
extends MarginContainer

export var obj=""
export var expr_list={"sig":""}
export(int) var value_from_model setget set_val
onready var panel_frame=get_node("frame")
onready var panel=get_node("frame/Panel")

func set_val(val):
    value_from_model=val
    if panel_frame != null:
        panel_frame.margin_right=value_from_model
    check_signal()
    
func check_signal():
    var new_style = StyleBoxFlat.new()
    var for_panel = StyleBoxFlat.new()
    #var panel_frame=get_node("frame")
    new_style.border_width_top=2
    new_style.border_width_bottom = 2
    new_style.border_width_left=2
    new_style.border_width_right=2
    new_style.border_color="#1bf408"
    new_style.bg_color='#0b0e0e'
    panel_frame.set('custom_styles/panel', new_style)
    for_panel.bg_color="#1bf408"
    panel.set('custom_styles/panel', for_panel)
    
    
func _ready():
    check_signal()
    set_val(value_from_model)
```

First my onready variables panel_frame and frame were in the funtion check_signal() as local variables. But I was getting an error "get_path: Cannot get path of node as it is not in a scene tree." , "get_node: (Node not found: "frame/Panel" (relative to "").) ". After I made them global and changed to onready var. And now I am getting this error.

[When I try to change va`value_from_model` in the inspector, the error appears again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFeA4.png)

[Here is my progress bar which has to be changing every time when I change the value_from_model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMsYu.png)

Comment: I really need help. I am stuck on this over 3 days :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `get_node` is failing, the node isn't there… So it gives you an error. That also explains why `set` fails: the variable that should have been initialized with `get_node` wasn't initialized.

Usually, that would be a matter of fixing a wrong path. You could even have Godot generate the correct path for you, by dragging the node over the script.

---

However, since `get_path` was also failing, I suspect you are facing a slightly more complex situation.

I believe you or Godot are setting `value_from_model` as part of the instantiation process, which triggers `set_val`, *before* the ready mechanism.

You can check with `is_inside_tree`. The pattern I often use is as follows:

```
func set_val(val):
    if value_from_model==val:
        return

    value_from_model=val
    if is_inside_tree():
        update_val()


func _enter_tree() -> void:
    update_val()


func update_val() -> void:
   if panel_frame != null:
       panel_frame.margin_right=value_from_model

   check_signal()
```

I'm going to suggest to **modify it to use `_ready` instead of `_enter_tree`**, since you need children nodes, and `_ready` will run after the children are ready. *However, remember that `_ready` will only run once, unless you call `request_ready`, which might be important if you are going to remove and add the node multiple times during runtime.*

*You could also use `yield` to wait until the node is ready or inside the scene tree, however, I have moved away from `yield`, that is another tale.*

Similarly, you should not need to do `set_val(value_from_model)` in `_ready`. Furthermore, you might even do `panel_frame.margin_right=value_from_model` inside of `check_signal`, and then you won't need two different methods (`check_signal` and `update_val`).

So we land into this:

```
func set_val(val):
    if value_from_model==val:
        return

    value_from_model=val
    if is_node_ready():
        check_signal()


func _ready() -> void:
    check_signal()


func _exit_tree() -> void:
    request_ready()


func check_signal() -> void:
   if panel_frame != null:
       panel_frame.margin_right=value_from_model

   # rest of the code
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I tried your answer and the code is working. But again that error occured in the output when I tried to change the value_from_model in the  inspector. I edited my question and added 2 shreenshots to it. How do I solve this one?

Comment: @Nika Could that be because the script reloaded but `_ready` didn't run in the editor? I'm thinking that reloading the project would fix it.

Comment: thank you for your help! Everything worked well, and yeah I just had to restart the program, and then it was fine :)